# (jQuery mobile) Dynamic grid display badly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i'm looking for something weird happening to me... I create a grid with header and with one line with random infos directly in the html file :

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <div class="ui-grid-d">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">Info1</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">Info2</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c">Info3</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-d">Info4</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-e">Info5</div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li> 
                <a href="#Select" class="ui-grid-d divider">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-d">
                        4
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-e">
                        5
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <p class="inner"></p>
        </ul>
```

Then i use the "inner" class to dynamically had a row with a javascript function, but it actually display ... badly. Here is the js line and the output:

```
$('.inner').append('<li> <a href="#Select" class="ui-grid-d divider" id="nextgrid"><div class="ui-block-a">1</div><div class="ui-block-b">2</div><div class="ui-block-c">3</div><div class="ui-block-d">4</div><div class="ui-block-e">5</div></a></li>');
```

[image]

Does anyone know why? Does it even happened to anyone?(I suspect the fact that some properties of the grid aren't considered by the js function, but really i'm not sure.)

EDIT

New try with the @Buzinas's suggestion :
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're inserting a `li` into a `p`, and the `li` should be placed into the `ul`.

Instead of using that `p` tag, you should get the `ul` and use `append` to insert your dynamic data.

**Update**

I've updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qcgga3x/1/) with what the solution you want.

The thing is that you must call `$('ul').listview('refresh');` every time you add/remove items.

Comment: Theoretically, no. The `append` method add what you're passing as parameter as the last child of the `node` you're trying to insert it.

Comment: Alright, I tried the thing u said, the output is better, but still, the output isn't the same. Weird.

Comment: If you can, create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so I can figure out what's happening there ;)

Comment: Yeah that's quite akward... I don't manage to make the button working for some reason... here is the code, if you see something obvious, otherwise i can't ask you to make the code works lol https://jsfiddle.net/4qcgga3x/

Comment: I've updated your fiddle and now it's working the way you want. It's in my updated answer.